# Router keep advertising itself on ipv6

Tags: networking, wireless-router, ipv6, icmp

I keep receiving the following router advertisement every few seconds from my router on ipv6 despite disabling my wireless ipv6 connection:

```
# tcpdump -vv 'ip6 and icmp6'
tcpdump: listening on wlth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:01:33.260428 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 56) fe80::220:70ff:feb3:91d2 > ff02::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 56
    hop limit 64, Flags [other stateful], pref low, router lifetime 0s, reachable time 0ms, retrans time 0ms
      rdnss option (25), length 24 (3):  lifetime 30s, addr: fe80::220:70ff:feb3:91d2
        0x0000:  0000 0000 001e fe80 0000 0000 0000 0220
        0x0010:  70ff feb3 91d2
      mtu option (5), length 8 (1):  1280
        0x0000:  0000 0000 0500
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 00:26:55:b0:92:d1
        0x0000:  0026 55b0 92d1
```

Is this behaviour normal? If not, how do I stop it?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Your router is IPv6-ready and just waiting for your ISP to give you some IPv6 prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a normal behavior for an IPv6 router to advertise the IPv6 subnet(s).

This is part of IPv6 Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP), which uses ICMPv6 to allow automatic configuration of IPv6 on hosts joining a new network.

If you want to disable this behavior, you must disable it on the router.

Comment: Thanks for the info. There is nothing of that sort on ipv4. And it is basically useless to me since my ISP does not support ipv6 natively.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow If your router allows, you could configure a [Unique Local Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) prefix for your network and communicate internally using IPv6. If you would like to play around with it. Alternatively, you could get a global prefix from a tunnel provider.